# Why won't this program compile? Why is this wrong?

Tags: c++

I know there is something wrong with the "if (isalpha(first))" but I dont know what to do to fix it. Can anyone tell me why this is wrong?

```
// 
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
char first[80];
cout << "\nWhat is your first name? ";
cin >> first;

if (isalpha(first))
cout << "\nNice Job, " << first << '\n';
else
cout << "\nThat is not a name!\n";

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: There's a problem with the `isalpha()` call; you should be using `isalpha((unsigned char)first[0])` or something similar, I believe (unless there's an overload for `isalpha()` in C++ that takes a null-terminated string). _(Question was edited while typing was in progress; it originally asked about a problem with `char first[80];`)_

Comment: @Greg. Sorry. I get a "Error: argument of type "char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "int"

Comment: @Jon I changed what line the error was on. I said "char first [80]" at first it was really where the isalpha is which you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isalpha(first))
```

`isalpha()` accepts `int` as parameter but you provided a `char[]` to it.

Comment: Strictly, `isalpha()` et al take a `char` converted to `unsigned char`.  If `char` is signed and the high bit is set, it makes a big difference.